# Humans from Venus coming to Earth discover their own past

Tags: story-identification, books

Book with theme of humans coming from Venus to unoccupied Earth, to discover ancient ruins and consequently their own history. Thousands of years earlier, warlike humans of Earth had mostly killed everyone off with a manufactured virus, and a group of survivors escaped to eventually settle on Venus, struggled to survive there and forgot their ancestors ever came from Earth, but eventually reinvented technology and space travel to get to Earth. I can't remember the author or title! I believe he is a living, contemporary author. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are seeking Echoes of an Alien sky by James P. Hogan.   He is a "contemporary" author though he recently died in 2010.   The plot description you listed matches up almost perfectly both from what I remember reading and from what is listed below.

[Fantastic Fiction Link](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/h/james-patrick-hogan/echoes-of-alien-sky.htm)

Comment: YES! That's it! Thank you thank you thank you! Now I can find and read his other books.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you enjoyed this one from Hogan, I am sure you will enjoy the others. I might recommend starting with Inherit the Stars (Giants Series 1).

Comment: Oh too, if you could select this as the correct answer, that would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not correct, but parts of Olaf Stapledon's great classic [Last and First Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_and_First_Men) do match: specifically, the Fifth Men colonize Venus after Earth becomes uninhabitable (not due to a virus, though earlier the Second Men kill off themselves with one they use to fend off invading Martians). And much later, the Sixteenth Men (now living on Neptune) discover (like the Fifth) a method of re-living the experiences of people in the past, and thereby learn the details of the previous races' history on Venus and Earth.